# React-table long page with many tables performance issue

Tags: performance, react-query, react-table

I am using react-table in next js and I have a page that contains tables which has different rows, all rows of tables are around 400, the problem is when I perform action, page freezes,

[I do such action]
[image]

I am using react-query. After the action I invalidate the main data and that results in rerender of the every row and that freezes the page for 4 to 6s. How can I improve the performance?

I tried useMemo inside Columns but didn't work

[image]